# Downloads in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: windows-10, wget

I am using the Ubuntu terminal on my Windows 10. I downloaded a file from the  Ubuntu terminal into a directory I created on the terminal. Right now I can't search for the file on my computer. Any idea where it went?

[image]

As you can see the file is there. But i dont know where is that directory or how to install that file.

Comment: Type `pwd` in the terminal and you will see the full path. `~` is a shortcut for the current users home directory. So it will likely be `/home/<username>/C:/Huvi` where `C:` is probably a directory you created and not the C: drive.

Comment: @codlord can I view the directory in my windows ?

Comment: @codlord  well I have only installed the ubuntu terminal in my windows laptop. Should I need to install ubuntu in my laptop ?

Comment: I think in the Windows 10 Ubuntu shell the Windows drives can be found at `/mnt/c` do an `ls /mnt` or ls `/mnt/c` to check. Then you could `cp` the file to `/mnt/c` or `/mnt/c/path`

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu system files are stored at:
**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs**

Your Ubuntu user account’s home folder is stored at:
**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME**

The root account’s home folder is stored at:
**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\root**

I hope it helps you